# Non-Euclidean geometry

Tags: geometry

Were all the five Euclid's postulates from the first book discarded to give rise to hyperbolic and elliptical geometry or only the Parallel Postulate was discarded?

Were all the 23 definitions and 48 prepositions from the first book incorporated in these non-Euclidean geometries?

Comment: only the fifth (and there are more than five postulates in Euclid's work).

Comment: +1 Damn...beat me to it :-) but I should point out in addition that the definition of a "straight line" also changes. A straight line is the shortest distance between two points and they look very different in different geometries.

Comment: All the 23 definitions ( and maybe the 48 prepositions ) from the first book are also encorporated in hyperbolic and eliptical geometry or just the four postulates ?

Comment: Definitions yes, propositions no, the parallel postulate is essential for many of the propositions of Book I.

Comment: I know, but only few of them used the fifth paralel.Can i say the ones that didn't use were encorporated ?

Comment: Yes. If you want to be careful, make a tree of dependencies.

Comment: If my memory serves well: The interesting thing is that Euclid wrote the Elements in such an order that the first propositions don't use the fifth postulate. However, from the point where this postulate is first used, it is necessary for all propositions that follow. I couldn't tell from memory at which proposition this happens, but that shouldn't be too hard to find out.

Comment: @The word "proposals" is misspelled.nerdy